# I have data frame with two columns and I would like to Fill missing column B value based on the column A value Range

Tags: python-3.x

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[123, 1232, 2233, 2233, 2233, 2233], 
                   "result":['', '', '', '', '', True]})
```

I would like to fill true in result column where ever the id is same in Column A values.

ex: I don't want to update the true for the id 123, 1232.

Could someone help me with this. I'm trying to use Bfill but true is getting updated for all the id's.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "same ID"? Are you showing your inputs or expected outputs? Why is there only one true value in `result`? Please also show us your code and current results or errors.

Comment: Sorry for that.. I need to update missing value as "true" in result column only for these id's(2233, 2233, 2233). as per my requirement if any one of the id is having the value is true then i need to update the missing values as true for the corresponding Id's only, and not to other id's.

Comment: ID Result
21231123489 
21231123489 
21231123489 
2123123 
2123123 
2239999 
2239999 
2239999 TRUE
2239999 TRUE
2239999 TRUE
2239999 TRUE
Here I need to update the value as true only for the id's 2239999. Similarly I have other id's as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `transform`:

```
df["result"] = df["result"].replace("", np.nan)
df["result"] = df.groupby("id")["result"].transform("first").fillna("")
```

Output:

```
     id result
0   123       
1  1232       
2  2233   True
3  2233   True
4  2233   True
5  2233   True
```

Comment: df.at[n,'result']=df.groupby("Id")["result"].transform("first").fillna("") ----  i tried this way in the code

Comment: Thanks Chirs, I have tried and got the below error : f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().